# Implementing Multiplex(Concurrency) in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Question :-

Using Java how will you allow multiple threads to run in a critical section  at the same time, but with an upper limit say 6. Not more than 6 threads should access the thread at the same time.

I have a feeling that the solution I did (given below) is wrong since only one thread can access the critical section because of **synchronized** keyword. Please can anybody confirm this and post other solutions if possible.

My Solution

---

```
package multiplex;

public class Multiplex {

    private static Multiplex multiplex = new Multiplex();
    private volatile static int counter = 0;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    multiplex.criticalSection();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        for(int index = 0; index < 100; index++){
            Thread thread = new Thread(run);
            thread.setName("Multiplex"+index);
            thread.start();
        }

    }

    public void criticalSection() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("counter is" + counter);
            synchronized (multiplex) {
                    if(counter <=5 ){
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("No Counter is " + counter);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Hello I am critical");
                    multiplex.notify();

                }else{
                    counter--;
                    System.out.println("Waiting Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + counter);

                    multiplex.wait();
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use either semaphore or **thread pool**, you would have help [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#sem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

```
// nrPermits is the number of simultaneous semaphore holders
final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(nrPermits);

// then:

semaphore.acquire(); // blocks until a permit is available
try {
    criticalSection();
} finally {
    semaphore.release();
}
```

Another solution would be to use a bounded `ThreadPool`, and a policy to put tasks on hold while the thread pool is full. This is what [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) does by default:

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrTasks);
// use Runnables or FutureTasks if the threads produce results
```

Comment: Thanks. As an after thought, How can this be done in pre Java 5 ?

Comment: Uuh... backport-util-concurrent? :p Honestly, that would be quite complicated. I have only ever done multithreading programming in Java 5+. For Java 4 I'll be of no help...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense to do this except in very rare case, but you can use a Semaphore.

A much simpler solution is to have a fixed size thread pool of 6 and submit Runnable tasks to it.  This will be much more efficient but also simpler to write/read.